# Developing multi tab windows

Tags: c#, tabs

let's say I want to make program settings menu like:

[image]

Many tab options that change the layout of the rest of the window

My program is in C# and I'm making it in Visual Studio

I tried to do it 2 ways:

1. Make the window super large with all possible layouts in the Form designer and then just resizing it to fit one of them at the time but this method works for like 4 tabs when you can fit them all at 1 screen. If it's large you have to work with slide bars and that's really impractical, laggy and for many tabs you even have to search them
2. Not using Form designer at all and hand write all the declarations, positions, sizes, colors etc. But like this it takes pretty a while even just to set up 1 button and there is no way I can fast see how it looks like

So the question is: Is there a magic way I don't know about to do this? And how is this made professionally?

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution for small number of views**

You can use a TextBox and ListView docked in a Panel docked left.

And a ControlTab docked fill in a panel named for example PanelMain docked fill at right with visible at false.

You will create any tabpage as option. In each tabpage you will put a panel docked fill and dedicated content in. On the listview item click event or itemchange, you will set the tabpage panel parent to PanelMain.

The little problem can be about spacing and the code file can be large (regions can be used).

**Advanced solution more clean for several views**

You can use the standard multipage pattern with one form per option/view, and do the same thing as exposed previously.

You create one form per view and put a panel docked fill embedding controls.

When the user click on the menu, you set the form main panel parent to the option form or the main panel of the options form.

*I hope I haven't written too badly in unverified English*.

*Feel free to open any new question centered on any atomic and code problem on this subject*.